# How to exclude a category from a mask

Tags: python, pandas, mask

```
sns.histplot(data=DS1[(DS1.TuWgt<30000) & (DS1.TuType!=1001)], x="TuWgt",hue="TuType",multiple="stack")
```

So this is the line I'm trying to run. TuType is a category.

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Categorical'

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator has a higher priority than the `<` and `!=` operators, so your code is being executed like this:

```py
sns.histplot(data=DS1[DS1.TuWgt < (30000 & DS1.TuType) != 1001], x="TuWgt",hue="TuType",multiple="stack")
```

...which is wrong (and confusing).
Instead, add parentheses around the conditions joined by `&`, like this:

```py
sns.histplot(data=DS1[(DS1.TuWgt<30000) & (DS1.TuType!=1001)], x="TuWgt",hue="TuType",multiple="stack")
```

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful. Now the code works, and I get a histogram, but the category that I want to exclude is still there.

Comment: You'll need to show us a sample of your dataframe in order for us to help with that. Since that's actually a slightly _different_ problem, I recommend opening a _new_ question for that. Link it here, and I'll see what I can do there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are your dtypes are, but if you are sure TuWgt and TuType are numeric only, try to wrap the conditions into parentheses:

```
sns.histplot(data=DS1[(DS1.TuWgt<30000) & (DS1.TuType!=1001)], x="TuWgt",hue="TuType",multiple="stack")
```

Otherwise `&` operation has higher priority, so you try to apply `&` to `30000` and `DS1.TuType`